# Why would my matrix rotations be going backwards in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, matrix, rotation

I am using a float4x4 matrix class i made back in the day.

I never used openGL until now and i have gotten into animation skinning.

But debugging my skeletons i realized that my positions for the interpolation are correct but the rotations are going backwards so if a person was to lean forward. the animation skeletons do lean forward but the rotations on those leans are going the opposite direction.

i do use quaternion calculations. I have done this before in DirectX but am i missing something different between openGL and directX?

I would just like maybe a link to an article or just someone to explain any major difference between the rotation angles or just hints why my rotations might be going the opposite direction

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you're running into an issue to do with the fact that the shader is looking for matrices to be column major as opposed to row major.  I.e. you might need to transpose your matrices.

Another issue might be the handedness of your space, OpenGL is right-handed so z is negative into the screen.

Another thing occurred to me.  There is no camera in OpenGL, rather, when you do your view transform you are performing the inverse transforming your geometry.

Comment: oh i transpose before i send the values over.

Comment: Are you using the fixed pipeline or programmatic pipeline? I.e., did you write your own shader? Or are you using glBegin/glEnd?

Comment: i wrote my own shader

Comment: What about multiplication order of matrices?  Column major matrices are multiplied in the opposite order.  Do you have any code you could post?  At this point I'm just shooting in the dark.

Comment: im doing model view projection umm I don't know if maybe skype would work? it's been such a hassle organizing all the stuff related to this to look into it deeper I've almost given up on online help lol. if not its ok i understand.  thanks for trying

Comment: Can you post your shaders?